# How to do a POST Request with PlayWright

Tags: javascript, post, request, playwright

I have been stuck with this for a bit. I need to test a website and I need to post info in order to test if it appears on the page.

What I have so far is this

```js
    (async () => {
        const browser = await webkit.launch();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.route('http://100.100.100.100/', route => route.fulfill({
            status: 200,
            body: body,
        }));
        await page.goto('https://theurlofmywebsite/');
        await page.click('button')
        await page.click('text=Login with LoadTest')
        await page.fill('#Username','username')
        await page.fill('#Password','password')
        await page.click('#loginButton')
        // await page.waitForSelector('text=Dropdown');
        await page.click('css=span >> text=Test')
        await page.click('#root > div > div > header > ul.nav.navbar-nav.area-tabs > li:nth-child(6) > a','Test')
        await page.waitForSelector('text=Detail')
        await page.screenshot({ path: `example3.png` })
        await browser.close();
    })();
    
    const body = [ my json post request ]
```

Comment: You can perform a post using page.evaluate

Comment: Can you elaborate what the issue is? If required, you can refer to this example: https://try.playwright.tech/?s=trqt9

Comment: The question is a bit unclear here. Usually, when testing, you want to test user-visible behavior. Trigger the post request with a button click/form submission and assert on the page content or navigation change accordingly. Posting something by hand bypasses functionality on the webpage and generally defeats the purpose of testing it.

Answer (score 4):

With version 1.19 it looks easy.

```
test('get response variable form POST in Playwright', async ({ request }) => {
  const response = await request.post(`/repos/${USER}/${REPO}/issues`, {
    data: {
      title: '[Bug] report 1',
      body: 'Bug description',
    }
  });
  expect(response.ok()).toBeTruthy();
}
```

See more on https://playwright.dev/docs/test-api-testing

Answer (score 3):

```js
jest.setTimeout(1000000);
let browser: any;
let page: any;
beforeAll(async () => {
    browser = await chromium.launch();
});
afterAll(async () => {
    await browser.close();
});
beforeEach(async () => {
    page = await browser.newPage();
});
afterEach(async () => {
    await page.close();
});



it("should work", async () => {
    await fetch("http://YOUAWESOMEURL", {
        method: "post",
        body: JSON.stringify(body),
    })
        .then((response) => console.log(response))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    await page.goto("https://YOUAWESOMEURL");
    await page.click("button");
    await page.click("text=Login");
    await page.fill("#Username", "YOURUSERNAME");
    await page.fill("#Password", "YOURPASSWORD");
    await page.click("#loginButton");
    // await page.click("css=span >> text=Load Test");
    await page.click(
        "#root > div > div > header > ul.nav.navbar-nav.area-tabs > li:nth-child(6) > a >> text=Test"
    );
    await page.waitForSelector("text=SOMETEXTYOUWANTTOCHECKIFTHERE");
    // await page.waitForSelector(`text=SOMEOTHERTEXTYOUWANTTOCHECKIFTHERE`);
    // Another way to check for success
    // await expect(page).toHaveText(`SOMEOTHERTEXTYOUWANTTOCHECKIFTHERE`);
    console.log("test was successful!");
});
```

Comment: This is what I wanted to do, launch a post request inside the test. It's quite easy, you just do a fetch inside the function.

Answer (score 2):

```
import { expect, request } from '@playwright/test';

const baseApiUrl = "https://api.xxx.pro/node-api/graphql";

test('API Search', async ({ request }) => {

        const search_query = `query  {me {  id username}}   `;

        const response = await request.post(baseApiUrl, {
            data: {
                query: search_query
            },
            headers: {
                authorization: `Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzcCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzd`
            }
        });

        const bodyResponse = (await response.body()).toString();
        expect(response.ok(), `${JSON.stringify(bodyResponse)}`).toBeTruthy();
        expect(response.status()).toBe(200);

        const textResponse = JSON.stringify(bodyResponse);
        expect(textResponse, textResponse).not.toContain('errors');
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).